# NPM Permission errors even after resetting ownership

Tags: javascript, npm, module, global

Been trying to install nodemon globally and although installed, I got a permission error when trying to run `nodemon app.js` in my terminal (using zsh). The following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/carlosgrijalva/.config/configstore/update-notifier-nodemon.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
    at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js:15:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

I found this article: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

And followed the instructions in option 1 by running the following command:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

I'm debating reinstalling node and since i'm using 6.11 and figured I might as well use the latest version but I'm unsure if that's the wisest move at this point. If anyone has any other suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to change the permission for `/Users/carlosgrijalva/.config/configstore/update-notifier-nodemon.json`  and maybe `/Users/carlosgrijalva/.config/configstore/`, because thats the file and/or directory node is complaining about.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Managed to fix it with 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm` and
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config`

Hope it fixes future issues too.